# How to select record from DataTable using linq with two different DataType of colums in DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

Hi i want to get single value from datatable with some condition
here is my code im getting this exception : **'Specified cast is not valid.'**
`

```
var result = from dc in dt.AsEnumerable()
where dc.Field<int>("YEAR") == 201803
select dc.Field<double>("VALUE");
```

after that i want to convert the for output

```
foreach (var c in result )
{
string temp = c.toString();
}
```

Comment: The loop is invalid (there's no `toString()` but the error complains that one of the stored values isn't an integer or double. It's impossible to say since you didn't include the full message and the code that creates `dt` is missing. Do the columns contain *strings* instead of numbers perhaps?

Comment: dt is fill from database.

Comment: And contains *what*? If `Year` is a string, `Field<int>()` can't cast it into an integer. Or perhaps the `VALUE` field is a `decimal` or `float`. Post the *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. Not just the message. You can easily copy the full exception content by clicking on the `Copy Details` button in the exception popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example. probably the input data is not in a proper type
also `ToString` typo

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("YEAR",typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("VALUE",typeof(double));
            dt.Rows.Add(201803, 123);
            dt.Rows.Add(201804, 12.34);

            var result = from dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
                         where dr.Field<int>("YEAR") == 201803
                         select dr.Field<double>("VALUE");

            foreach (double c in result)
            {
                string temp = c.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks There is Int64 DataType in DataTable